# Identify connection lost between Socket Server and Socket Client in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp

Friends,

I wrote a Socket Client which will send the Socket Server some data and get some response from Server. This process will be running once in every 2 seconds.

Now what I need to know is How we can identify the connection lost between Server and Client?

I need this to be implemented in the Client side. If there is no connection then Client should automatically close the connection. Once the connection with the server is available in the next attempt it should connect automatically.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a vb.net developer, but this is how it works in most languages.

Writing to a lost/closed connection will fail, the client will then know that he needs to reconnect.

It's never possible to know if a connect attemt to a server will succedd before you have done it, so your client should try to reconnect in a loop with a sleep/wait period in between each connection attempt.